# How to handle the data received to save it in the database Laravel and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add the product with multiple images to the database without refreshing the page, I don't get any errors on console but I see the long text which starting like this

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = ....
```

and the error comes from this line `console.log(data);`. The product has a relationship with ProductsPhoto,how can I make it add the product to the database?

Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $formInput=$request->except('filename');

    $product = product::create(array_merge($formInput, [
        'seller_id'=> Auth::user()->id,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]));
    foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
       $filename = $photo->store('public/photos');
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    }
}
```

Blade

```
  <div class="panel-body">

   <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" id="token"/>

     <label for="pro_name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pro_name" id="pro_name" placeholder="Enter product name">

        <label for="pro_price">Price</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pro_price" id="pro_price" placeholder="Enter price">

        <label for="pro_info">Description</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pro_info" id="pro_info" placeholder="Enter product description">

           <label for="stock">Stock</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock" id="stock" placeholder="Enter stock">

        <label  for="category_id">Choose Category</label>
           <select name="category_name" id="category_name">
             <option value=""> --Select Category -- </option>
               @foreach ($categoryname_array as $data)
                <option value="{{ $data->name }}"  >{{$data->name}}</option>
                 @endforeach
               </select>

 <label for="photos">Choose 5 Images</label>
  <input  "multiple="multiple" id="photos" name="photos[]" type="file">

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" id="btn"/>

</div>
```

Ajax

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn").click(function(){
    var category_name = $("#category_name").val()
    var pro_name = $("#pro_name").val();
    var pro_price = $("#pro_price").val();
    var stock = $("#stock").val();
    var pro_info = $("#pro_info").val();
    var photos = $("#photos").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        data: "pro_name=" + pro_name + "&pro_price=" + pro_price + "&stock=" + stock + "&_token=" + token + "&category_name=" + category_name + "&pro_info=" + pro_info + "&photos=" + photos,
        url: "<?php echo url('seller/product') ?>",
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }

    });
  });
});
```

Route

```
 Route::post('seller/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Comment: Did you check network section in chrome developer tools? If not click, `ctrl+shift+i`, once the dev tools show up select 'Network' and then fire the event again (submit the form) then click the link that will show up and check the response.

Comment: I see this
   `"message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()",
    "exception": "ErrorException",`  when  I click the response @MEDZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error you added in the comments, the value inside `$request->photos` is not iteratable, which make sense because you do not use Form Data to handle upload.

Normal ajax does not handle file upload so you have to use [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

```
var token = $("#token").val();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        formData.append('_token', token); // adding token
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo url('seller/product') ?>",
            data: formData, //just that without variables
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
            processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So I just found that the product is added to the database but not the image and I tried to change the code and use the one with `formData` but it doesn't add the product @MEDZ

Comment: Well, try to dd($request->all()) then check Network section on 'preview' tab and let me know if the request holds any data.

Comment: Also i do not see <form> tag in your code .. make sure you have one because that is what form data is using.

Comment: Are you using  <form> tag in your html template?

Comment: If I put this `<form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">` I get an error `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.` @MEDZ

Comment: You do not need method or any attribute just the tag, so that this `$('form')[0];` can work properly. Also, i updated my answer to include the token with it's new name _token.

Comment: So when I submit the form it shows `failed to load response data` on console `preview/response` @MEDZ

Comment: Ok That's a develop tools issue. Now instead of using dd(), just return $request.all() and check it in console.log() in console tab (instead of Network); also check how the function worked. Did anything saved in Database? I've just tried a close example and it worked with me.

Comment: it doesn't save anything in database and also where is that console.log()? @MEDZ

Comment: console.log(data) in success() callback.

Comment: So how do I check on `console.log(data)` ?@MEDZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203381/discussion-between-medz-and-joh).